# How to combine two or three characters to one integer/character

Tags: c, algorithm, encoding

I am getting characters from UART for example "\n43\n" or "\n912\n". I intend to make this an integer in order to compare the values in my application.

Example:

```
     int a = 43;
     int b;
     /*Combine the character getting from the uart copy to integer "b";*/
     if(a==b)
     {
         /*perform some operation*/
     }
```

Comment: Have a look at [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html).

Comment: Seems to be you want to parse numbers. Correct your question to make that clear please. Especially in case that's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int number;
char a[30] = "\n43\n";
number = atoi(a);
printf("magic is %d",number);
if(number == 43)
   printf("This works....!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Have you heard ever `atoi()`

**Edit**:

```
int main()
{
int number = 0;
char a[30];
a[0] = '4';
a[1] = '3';
a[2] = '\0';
number = atoi(a);
printf("magic is %d",number);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about character? for example char a = 43; I don't want a[2] = "43"

Comment: for that you can go ahead by 
number = a - '0';

Comment: Your above code is not working.

Comment: or you can make new string with a[0] = 43 and then a[1] = '\0' and then give it to atoi();

Comment: see mu edit in ur answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do following safely as character ASCII  is less than  `256` .

```
int combine(char a, char b, char c)
{
    return (a << 20) | (b << 10) | c;
}
```

This works when value of a,b,c is less than around `1000` , as `2^10 = 1024` .

To get them back :

```
a = combined >> 20;
b = (combined >> 10) & 0x3ff;
c = combined & 0x3ff;
```